# Python: How do you check what is in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

How do you check what package and version are installed inside virtualenv?
My thought was to create `requirement.txt` file.  But, is there another way to do this from CLI?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Once you activate your virtual environment, you should be able to list out packages using `pip list` and verify version using `python --version`.

Answer (score 7):

`pip list` will show you all the packages that are installed for the virtualenv. I see you are wanting to create the requirements.txt file from a CLI, so you can run this command

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

This will give you a `requirements.txt` file inside your current directory, for *ALL* the packages and libraries that are installed for that virtualenv.

Personally, I like using [pigar](https://github.com/Damnever/pigar). All you need to do after installing it is run `pigar` and it will search through your Python files inside the current directory and create a `requirements.txt` file for you based on all your imports from those files.